# Can you hard code IBActions and IBOutlets, rather than drag them manually in Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibaction, iboutlet

Is it possible to to hard code the `IBAction`s and `IBOutlet`s in code, instead of drag-connecting them in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is poosible...

sample code

```
UIButton *btnDetail = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] ;

        [btnDetail setFrame:CGRectMake(250.0f, 15.0f, 65.0f, 20.0f)] ;
        //btnDetail.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [btnDetail setTitle:@"Detail" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnDetail setTitleColor: [UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnDetail.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
        [btnDetail setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [btnDetail sizeThatFits:btnDetail.frame.size];
        [self.view addSubview:btnDetail];
//IBAction
        [btnDetail addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(ShowSavingAccountDetail:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [btnDetail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-detail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I dont know if this matters or not (because I'm new), but I had to move the IBAction portions behind the message to the view to add the button. Then confirmed it was working with an NSLog message confirming it was pressed. I tied a sender.selected == YES then print else so on and so on.

Answer (score 13):

The concept and sole purpose of IBAction and IBOutlet is to provide Interface Builder with means to connect the xib with your code.

If you don't want to use Interface Builder with your code, you don't need IBAction or IBOutlet, you need them ONLY to use objects (buttons, textfields, etc.) that were instanciated in your xib from your classes.

With that said, mihirpmehta's answer is the correct way to programmatically add UI elements to your view and add actions to them.