# to connect button outlet to file owner programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have created the outlet and property. Now can One please help me how can I connect outlet to file owner programmatically by giving some example or tutorial.Thnks in Advance.
Following is my outlet.

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btnStatus;

@property(nonatomic ,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btnStatus;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544279/can-you-hard-code-ibactions-and-iboutlets-in-xcode-rather-then-drag-them-manuall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IBOutlet` is not at all special.  In fact, it's just a macro that evaluates to nothing.  It is just a signal to Interface Builder when it reads the source file.  Just set it to whatever object you want, as you would with any property assignment.

Take a look at http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSButton (in general a fairly useful site) for examples.