# Hard Coding a button to an IBAction in xcode

Tags: xcode, button, ibaction, hardcode

when I google the title of my question I get another stackoverflow question that was answered that has been really helpful and explains most of what I need to do with hard coding a button. The problem is that when it is tied to an action it resembles this...

[btnDetail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-detail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Im looking to tie the button directly to an IBAction that I've already created called exitMovie so I was hoping to do something like this...

[button setAction: [IBAction.exitMovie] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

or something like that but nothing I have tried has worked. How do I do this correctly?

below is the link to the the aforementioned hardcode that I used for the most part.
[Can you hard code IBActions and IBOutlets, rather than drag them manually in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544279/can-you-hard-code-ibactions-and-iboutlets-in-xcode-rather-then-drag-them-manuall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found it yourself in the last question:

```
[button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(exitMovie:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: That got rid of all errors but when I run it and attempt to press that button I get a signal SIGABRT that states:

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController exitMovie:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf244410'

Comment: I take this to mean that I need to implement the method exitMovie inside of ViewController but Im pretty sure I did. How exactly does it want me to implement exitMovie in case I'm doing it wrong? I just initialized exitMovie in the .h and implemented it in the .m. Is there something more I'm suppose to do?